# MDX query for Microsoft Adventure Work DW 2012

Tags: mdx

It's the first time I touch MDX and I would like to get the query

- Get the **average Internet Sales Amount** over different **cities** and different **product categories** over two **fiscal years 2007** and **2008**.

The following is my MDX query, but it failed to compile.

```
SELECT
{ [Geography].[City].CHILDREN } ON COLUMNS,
{ [Product].[Category].CHILDREN } ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE ( 
    [Measures].[Measures].[Internet Average Sales Amount], 
    [Date].[Fiscal Year].&[2007], 
    [Date].[Fiscal Year].&[2008]
)
```

The above query come with an error

> Query (7, 1) The Fiscal Year hierarchy is used more than once in the Crossjoin function.

Comment: How can I select Year-2007 and Year-2008 in the where statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following. `:` is the range operator. For more information [click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146001.aspx).

```
SELECT
{ [Geography].[City].CHILDREN } ON COLUMNS,
{ [Product].[Category].CHILDREN } ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE ( 
    [Measures].[Measures].[Internet Average Sales Amount], 
    [Date].[Fiscal Year].&[2007] : [Date].[Fiscal Year].&[2008]
)
```

It's been a while since I used MDX, but I think you will have to change more then that to get the desired result.

Comment: Do you mean the query is not match the desired question?

Comment: Yes I've doubts in your query, but I'm not sure about it. So try the part with the range operator, IMHO the error you described should not be raised again.

Comment: So this worked already. Regarding your query. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 2):

It's the first time I touch MDX, I am still confusing with SQL query.

For instance, if we are looking for Internet Sales Amount over different cities and different product categories.

According to the desired requirement, is the following MDX query COULD fulfill the requirement.

```
SELECT
    { [Geography].[City].CHILDREN } ON COLUMNS,
    { [Product].[Category].CHILDREN } ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
```

I have a little bit confuse in SELECT and WHERE clause

What I expect the above statement is something like this, one axis shows all possible **cities** and another one shows all possible **product category**, and each cell is the **aggregated Internet Sales Amount**.

For instance.

```
       New York | Tokyo | ...
Car       $123  |  $50  | ...
Toys      $456  |  $100 | ...
```

I.e. New York has $123 Internet Sales Amount for Car

Is the MDX query fulfill my expectation?